# date format is not working monthpicker

Tags: jquery, laravel-4

I have a month picker in my form in laravel 4.2. While changing the month, the month and year are shown like 05/2015. But i need it to be in the format May, 2015.

```
{{ HTML::style('public/asset/css/smoothness/jquery-ui.css') }}
{{ HTML::style('public/asset/css/MonthPicker.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js') }} 
{{ HTML::script('public/asset/js/MonthPicker.min.js') }}    
{{ HTML::script('public/asset/js/MonthPicker.js') }}    
Query(document).ready(function() {
$("#SearchVal").val('');

var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();

var _picker = jQuery('#SearchVal').MonthPicker({

    ShowIcon: false

            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that manually on change event :

```
var monthsLabels = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

var picker = jQuery('#SearchVal').MonthPicker({
    ShowIcon: false,
    OnAfterChooseMonth: function(){
        var elts = picker.val().split('/');
        picker.val(monthsLabels[parseInt(elts[0])-1]+', '+elts[1]);
    }
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeZap/346/)

Answer (score 0):

hello bro try to see [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) will help you it's about **Datepicker**

Comment: Sorry. I am asking for month picker. not date picker